# Store Operators like >= OR <= in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have certain values that are needed for validation in Forms, either they look like `Value X >= 0` but it could also be `X <= 0`, it depends on what operator should be used. How can I store such a value?

(I use MS SQL Server + Access as Frontend)

I basicly wanna store the Value and if it needs to be bigger than or smaller than.

Comment: How then you would use those values after you store them? What are you trying to do? just store them and that's it?

Comment: @Sami I wanna use them for conditional Formatting, ergo the field value needs to be `<= 0` just as an example

Comment: It seems to (if I understand) that you just need a boolean `TRUE/FALSE` for `>0` and `<0` which is `BIT` datatype in SQL Server.

Comment: Can't you just create a computed column for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the value, as usual, in a field, and the operator in another field as *Short Text*.

The you can use *Eval*:

```
Result = Eval("" & [ValueField] & [OperatorField] & "0")
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I have this as the Conditional Formatting in one of the Cols for example `Eval("" & [EidamCI] & ELookup("Operator";"dbo_Rohstoffanalyse_Sollwerte";"Rohstoff = 'Eisenoxid' AND Messwertbezeichnung = 'EidamCI'";"Zeitpunkt DESC") & "0,2")`, problem is that this doesnt rly work, what does the function return? A boolean value or?

Comment: ELookup is your own function, so can't tell, but I guess `"0,2"`should read `"0.2"` and _semicolons_ perhaps _commas_.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your value as it is, and to check if this value is positive or not you have two ways

- First one

Create a computed column to check the `Value` column as

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(
  YourValue INT,
  IsPositive AS CASE WHEN YourValue < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
);

INSERT INTO YourTable (YourValue) VALUES
(1), (-1);

SELECT *
FROM YourTable;
```

- Second one

Use a `CASE` expression (or even you can create a view) as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN YourValue < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END IsPositive,
       --...
FROM YourTable;
```